# How do I extract a value from this json_decode?

Tags: php, json

I have got this result using json decode from an api call. but I dont know how to extract "VALUE" from this result..

```
$obj=json_decode($json_string);
print_r($obj);

stdClass Object ( [status] => OK [data] => stdClass Object ( [trends] => stdClass Object ( [rank] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 201011 [value] => 7196 ) ) ) [trends_low_sample] => [query_cost] => 1 [trends_frequency] => monthly ) )
```

I need only "7196" from this result. how do I do this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah!  Based on your updated code you're tring to get the value from PHP not Javascript?  Personally I use `json_decode($json_string,true);` to get an associative array ([json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode)), if you do that it should be accessible as:

```
echo $obj["data"]["trends"]["rank"][0]["value"];
```

As an object it's accessible as:

```
echo $obj->data->trends->rank[0]->value;
```